# Image logo not loaded on refresh page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates

I have a strange thing in `App.vue`,
for example, I have a route link, consider it is, `localhost/tools` or the route like this. The image logo will be shown.

Please have a look at this image
[image: example]

and when we for example click on another route, it will be shown. But the problem is, the problem will happen when I refresh the page at the route like, we consider it is `localhost/purchase/order`, I will give the gif image.

[image]

Is it strange? And then when I do a inspect element, it couldn't load the image

[image]

If you wanna see my code, this is my `App.vue`,

```
<----- This is for my logo image ----->
<a href="" class="sidebar-toggle">
    <img class="svg" :src="'./dashboard/img/svg/bars.svg'" alt="img">
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/tools">
    <img class="svg dark" :src="'./dashboard/img/Logo_Dark.png'" alt="logo">
    <img class="light" :src="'./dashboard/img/Logo_white.png'" alt="logo">
</a>

<----- This is for my dynamic user image ----->
<a href="javascript:;" class="nav-item-toggle">
  <img v-bind:src="`./dashboard/img/author/profile/`+user.avatar" alt="User" class="rounded-circle"> {{user.name}}
</a>
```

This is my `Resources/App.js`

```
import App from './components/App.vue';
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        return {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    },
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
});
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({
    router,
    vuetify,
    render: function (h) {
        return h(App)
    }
})).$mount("#app");
```

Can anyone help me for this issue?
Thank you before. :)

Comment: Don't bind `src` to a literal string. Just set it directly: `src="./dashboard/img/Logo_Dark.png"`.

Comment: so how if it is dynamic image sir?
for example like this,
`<a href="javascript:;" class="nav-item-toggle">
<imgv-bind:src="`./dashboard/img/author/profile/`+user.avatar" alt="User"
class="rounded-circle"> {{user.name}}</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of relative path is a mistake. `./dashboard/img/svg/bars.svg` at `localhost/purchase/order` will try to load an image from `localhost/purchase/order/dashboard/img/svg/bars.svg`. This could be seen in network tab but wasn't debugged.

The image is originally loaded because it's loaded when base URL is `localhost/` and image URL isn't changed later.

If an image is located at root, the link should be `/dashboard/img/svg/bars.svg`

Comment: I already edit my issue sir, especially on code `App.vue` section. Please sir.

Comment: I see. The solution stays the same. You load an image from wrong url. You can see this in devtools.

Comment: Already change to your suggested sir.
But when i refresh the page, it still the same sir.

Comment: Please, debug where the image is loaded from when it's successful and it's unsuccessful. It's only possible on your side.

Comment: I just wanna make sure, did I have to debug on inspect element sir?

Comment: It's Network tab in devtools. Do a research on it. It's very hard to develop front end apps without it.

Comment: Okay sir, I am doing a debugging. But when I doing that, the Logo_Dark is not loaded. I don't know why. [from_this](http://prnt.sc/1bopzcu), and when I refresh my browser [to_this](http://prnt.sc/1boqpam). Please, sir.

Comment: You likely need to find it in all urls and not images. I'd expect that that a response is index or 404 page so it doesn't count as images. What you look for is what url it's loaded from. It should differ in both cases. Basically you need to check two things, `<img>` src starts with `/` and not `./`, and `<base>` is `/`, these are two things that affect the situation.

Comment: I already solve this sir. I just add `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` on url link src sir